# showing toolbar buttons on a navigation controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

hi i know i'm missing something because it seems pretty easy all over the web.
I'm adding buttons to my toolbar, 
the toolbar is showing. but without any buttons.
this is my code :

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"secondPage";
    UIBarButtonItem *deleteAllItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete All"
                                                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered   
                                                                      target:self
                                                                      action:@selector(deleteAllAction:)] autorelease];


    UIBarButtonItem *searchNearbyItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Search Nearby"
                                                                          style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                         target:self
                                                                         action:@selector(searchNearbyAction:)] autorelease];

    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];
    self.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                      deleteAllItem,
                      searchNearbyItem,
                      nil];

}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: I created a new Navigation Controller based project, copied this code as the viewDidLoad on the RootViewController and it worked first time.  Could you give a little more context. Are you attempting this at the root controller?

Comment: yes you're right, it also works with me on my rooViewController :S. that's weird

Comment: ohh i got it, during my trials i added the method 
`- (void)setToolbarItems:(NSArray *)toolbarItems animated:(BOOL)animated` so it overrid the initial method :S ... sorry for the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the items via:

```
- (void)setItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animated
```

**Note:** Be sure to set this on your view controller, do not set it on the `UIToolbar` instance directly.

Comment: thank you, but this adds them in the navigationBar, i want to add them in the toolbar in the bottom